# First test with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I mactually trying to run my first unit test with mocha using this code :

```
var assert = require('assert');


var returnCool = function () {
    return 1;
}

describe("Array contains", function () {
    it('should return-1 when the value is not present', function () {
        returnCool().should.equal(1);
    });
});
```

The problem is that my code is actually failing everytime.
I tried with the sample in mocha website :

```
describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
      [1,2,3].indexOf(5).should.equal(-1);
      [1,2,3].indexOf(0).should.equal(-1);
    })
  })
})
```

And it fails too.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not calling your assertion library. You are currently calling `.should()` on an integer

Answer (score 1):

You have included an `assert` library but are using `should` - style asserts. Either include [should.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/should) or use `assert`-style asserts (`assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(5), -1)`)